# Creating a google app script that reads a file name from myDrive and places it in a folder based on file name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble creating an app script that can read a file name and from that file name move the file from myDrive to a designated folder. Ultimately I want to create an app that reads a naming convention of PR_P50_MP26_OtherContent.pdf and puts that file into the MP26 folder which is in the PR folder which is in the P50 Folder. When I run the script it sends my file to the wrong folder.

Goal: to move "PR_P50_MP286_LineLowering_2006_463.pdf" file into the PR Folder which is under the P50 Folder.

What happens when I run the code is it goes to the test folder in the else statement.

```
function MoveFiles(){
var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var packagedFile = file.getName();
    if (packagedFile.indexOf("PR_P50"))
    {  
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("PR folder of P50 Folder");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);
    }
    else{
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("My test Folder");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the code but the one error you mentioned can be fixed by replacing

```
var packagedFile = file.getname()
```

with

```
var packagedFile = file.getName()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change that and it moved the same error down to my if statement. I tried a couple things such as substituting .contains with .include and changing my file to packageFile on the subsequent lines, but still get the same type error displayed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `getFolderbyId` Which is looking for the folders given ID. Try getting the ID of the folder which should be part of the url. You should also declare your folder variable outside of the `while` loop.

> `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/FOLDERIDHERE`

This will atleast be able to get the file in the correct folder. If you wish to do it by folder name you will have to call on `getFolderByName("PR folder of p50 folder")` which will return a fileIterator so you will have to loop through it, but if you know there is only 1 folder with that name you will be able to set folder as `var folder = folders.next()`.  Either way you choose to do it, you should now be able to get the file into your desired folder.

```
function MoveFiles(){
var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
var 1stdestination = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERIDHERE");
var 2nddestination = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERIDHERE");
  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var packagedFile = file.getName();
    if (packagedFile.indexOf("PR_P50"))
    {  

    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);
    }
    else{

    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file); 
    }
  }
}
```

I did something similar here

```
var JobFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('MYFOLDERIDHERE');
  //Other stuff here
  if(!results.isBeforeFirst() ){
    throw new Error('Job does not exist'); 
  } else {
    if(jobId in JobFolder.getFilesByName(jobId) )
    {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(jobId); 
      var url = ss.getUrl();
      return {url:url, jobId:jobId};

    } else 
    {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(jobId);
      ss.insertSheet('Job Materials');
      ss.insertSheet('Job Operations');
      ss.insertSheet('Job Notes');
      ss.insertSheet('Employees Clocked On');
      var temp = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
      JobFolder.addFile(temp);


      var url = ss.getUrl();
      return {url:url, jobId:jobId};
    }
  }
```